# What does it mean by variable[[n]] in R?

Tags: web-scraping, rvest

I am learning web scraping during these lock down days. What does the second line of code mean in R?

tab <- h %>% html_nodes("table")

tab <- tab[[2]]

Comment: It is for subsetting: https://adv-r.hadley.nz/subsetting.html

Comment: Hiya. I’m voting to close this question because it is more of a tutorial request. Hopefully link above will help.

Answer (score 0):

The first line returns a list of tables (there are a few tables in the source page). `tab[[2]]` is the second one.